# when i append a value the whole array is changing to the appended value

Tags: swift, append

I append in the for loop but for some reason instead of appending at the end it changes all the existing values in the array.

```
let a = 2

class people {
    var name = " "
    var height = Int()
}

var trial = " "

var p = [people]() 
var user = people()
for i in 0...a-1{

    if(i==0){
        user.name =  "jack"
        user.height = 180
    }
    else {
        user.name =  "ryan"
        user.height = 120
    }

    p.append(user)
    print(p[i].name, p[i].height);

}
for i in 0...a-1 {
    print(p[i].name, p[i].height);
}
```

expectd: - 
jack 180
ryan 120
jack 180 
ryan 120

result:- 
jack 180
ryan 120
ryan 120
ryan 120

Comment: Note that it is Swift convention to name your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: var user = people() declare in for loop

Comment: You should use a struct, declare its properties as constants and use its default initialiser `struct People {`
    `let name: String`
    `let height: Int`
`}`
`let people: [People] = [.init(name: "jack", height: 180), .init(name: "ryan", height: 120)]`

`for person in people {`
    `print(person.name, person.height)`
`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create only one `instance` of `people` and add this `instance` in your array for two times. but the problem is when you assign the value for the second time it replaces the previous value of the same `instance`.

You have to create  new `instnse` of `people` inside your `for loop` for every new user. like below

```
let a = 2

class people {
    var name = " "
    var height = Int()
}

var trial = " "

var p = [people]() 
//var user = people() remove this line from here and add inside for-loop
for i in 0...a-1{
    var user = people() // add this line here.

    if(i==0){
        user.name =  "jack"
        user.height = 180
    }
    else {
        user.name =  "ryan"
        user.height = 120
    }

    p.append(user)
    print(p[i].name, p[i].height);

}
for i in 0...a-1 {
    print(p[i].name, p[i].height);
}
```